# What are the receptions of Olivet Assembly in these countries?

Tags: united-states, denomination, china, korea

What are the receptions and reputations of Olivet Assembly in these countries?

- [US](https://olivetassembly.org/)
- South Korea
- China (Is it also called Young Disciples of Jesus (耶稣青年会)?)

From limited search results, it looks like it was founded in South Korea. There are also some articles about it on American and Chinese websites, with different attitudes. Is it legal and well accepted by the governments or societies in the three countries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Tim, I don’t know why you are asking people to dig into obscure religious denominations in South Korea and in China.  This is part of what I found when I started to research into the World Olivet Assembly and the Olivet University in San Francisco, founded by [David Jang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Jang)

> David Jang is a Korean professor, Christian theologian, and pastor. He has founded several Christian organizations, including Olivet University in San Francisco, Christian Today headquartered in Korea, Christian Daily Korea, and Christianity Daily in Los Angeles, CA. He served as a member of the North American Council of the World Evangelical Alliance (WEA) from 2007 to 2018, the former president of World Olivet Assembly, the founder and first international president of Olivet University, and current president of the Holy Bible Society. Source: https://www.holybiblesociety.org/aboutus/

> In 2006, Jang handed over the presidency of the university to Dr. David James Randolph in order to concentrate on mission field work. Jang continues to serve at Olivet University as a professor of theology and international president.

> In 2014, a Mother Jones story documented that former religious followers of Mr. Jang said that they were recruited from China and brought to the U.S. on student visas to study at Olivet University, but spent most of their time working illegally, for very little pay, churning out clickbait for the International Business Times, which was started in 2006 by two of David Jang’s followers, Etienne Uzac and Johnathan Davis.

> In 2018, the Manhattan District Attorney charged it in a fraud and money laundering scheme. Olivet pled guilty to several charges and paid a $1.25 million fine. Tracy Davis, the president of Olivet University at the time of the guilty plea, was recently Dean for Academic Affairs. Her husband Johnathan Davis owns 50 percent of Newsweek. Two former executives of Jang-affiliated enterprises pleaded guilty to money laundering and fraud in 2019.

> In June 2022, a North Carolina judge ordered the arrest of Rev. JianGang "Frank" Lan in a counterfeit goods case that has drawn the attention of federal investigators looking into whether a church led by Jang was laundering money for criminals in the United States and China. On June 30, the New York State Education Department officially ended Olivet's authorization to operate in the state citing that their failings "are part of a larger pattern of poor administration and addressing such problems only after being caught in a criminal conspiracy." In March 2023, it was widely reported that California's Attorney General had filed a complaint to close down Olivet University due to several violations.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Jang#Olivet_University

> In 2012, a Christianity Today article raised questions whether Jang had any connections with the Unification Church and his being seen by some people as the "Second Coming of Christ", accusations that have been disputed as baseless by the Christian Council of Korea and the World Evangelical Alliance, among others. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Jang#Other_activities

The assembly first began in 2000 as a loose association of churches planted by alumni of Olivet Theological College and Seminary. The network’s development culminated in the inauguration of Olivet Assembly of USA in 2007 as members of the World Olivet Assembly.

[The beliefs of the Olivet Assembly](https://olivetassembly.org/about-us/what-we-believe/) may seem to be orthodox but you will have to make up your own mind about whether it is legal in the U.S. and in other countries.  I’m beginning to wonder why you are posting questions like this.

Comment: thanks. I am not familiar with the specific denomination in the specific countries and if it is allowed to operate with regards to the religious freedom in the specific countries. I found a few opposing opinions about it, although I have been having limited internet access. I was wondering why you wonder why I posted the questions.

Comment: plus, I might have been participating in a congregation of the specific denomination, without knowing that, even though I asked for that a few times. See one of my previous post, and maybe they feel it unsafe to reveal their identity in PRC.

Comment: I am not sure its status in US, with just a few search results. I found nothing about its status in South Korea. Its status in PRC is more of a mystery. Theologically I couldn't tell if they are orthodox, and my experiences with the congregation might have not been long enough for me to do so.